# Problems with date_decimal

Tags: r, date, lubridate

I am trying to convert dates into decimal for some purpose and when I need the date in the original format using `date_decimal` function, it is not returning the correct actual date.

When I use `(tz = "EST")` in date_decimal, it is showing the correct date, but I am not sure what the reason is for its failure in the first place, let alone how it works using "EST".

Can anyone share how `lubridate` converts date to decimal and vice versa?!

```
library(lubridate)
temp <- c('2015-01-01', '2015-02-01', '2015-03-01','2015-04-01', '2015-05-01', '2015-06-01', '2015-07-01', '2015-08-01', '2015-09-01', '2015-10-01', '2015-11-01','2015-12-01')
temp_decimal <- decimal_date(as.Date(temp,format = "%Y-%m-%d"))
temp_date <- as.Date(date_decimal(temp_decimal))
temp_date

[1] "2015-01-01" "2015-01-31" "2015-02-28" "2015-04-01" "2015-04-30" "2015-05-31" "2015-07-01" "2015-07-31" "2015-09-01" "2015-10-01" "2015-10-31" "2015-12-01"
```

Expected output is:

```
[1] "2015-01-01" "2015-02-01" "2015-03-01" "2015-04-01" "2015-05-01" "2015-06-01" "2015-07-01" "2015-08-01" "2015-09-01" "2015-10-01" "2015-11-01" "2015-12-01"
```

Comment: What's wrong with `dec <- as.numeric(as.Date(temp)); as.Date(dec, origin="1970-01-01")`?

Comment: This seems like a case of [floating-point precision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508518/why-are-these-numbers-not-equal).

Comment: @jay.sf I need to use the decimal version of lubridate for some timeseries functionalities.

Comment: @RuiBarradas any idea why it is working in case when I use ```as.Date(date_decimal(temp_decimal,tz = "EST"))```